# Is there a way to get this union to work with this intersection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

See the commented error right at the bottom.  It looks like the problem is because it is trying to assign to a type made out of an intersection of the many component props.  Based on my types so far I was expecting it to know that the props were appropriate for the component but apparently not.  How can this be avoided so that it checks the type of the props is ok for the given component?

```
type ComponentAProps = {
  a: string;
};

function ComponentA (props: ComponentAProps) {
  return <div>component a</div>;
}

type ComponentANode = {
  Component: typeof ComponentA,
  props: React.ComponentProps<ComponentANode['Component']>
};

type ComponentBProps = {
  b: string;
};

function ComponentB (props: ComponentBProps) {
  return <div>component a</div>;
}

type ComponentBNode = {
  Component: typeof ComponentB,
  props: React.ComponentProps<ComponentBNode['Component']>
};

type ExampleNode = ComponentANode | ComponentBNode;

type UiComponentArgs = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  node: ExampleNode;
};

function UiComponent({ children, node }: UiComponentArgs) {
  const Component = node.Component;
  const props = node.props;
  // solution: const props = node.props as ComponentANode['props'] & ComponentBNode['props'];

  return (
    <Component {...props} />
    // Type '{ a: string; } | { b: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ComponentAProps & ComponentBProps'.
    // Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type 'ComponentBProps'.(2322)
  );
}
```

Comment: The intersection occurs because to call a union of functions, the parameters must satisfy all function signatures. To do that, you must intersect all the signatures of the functions together.

Comment: Ah thanks.  That makes sense now you point it out.  I've edited the code to include the answer as a comment.

Comment: Better yet, answer the question yourself - but I still believe there's a better solution that is type safe and doesn't require an assertion.